Is there an simple derivation of the solution to the Submarine Paradox in terms of Special Relativity?
In 1989 James Supplee formulated the Relativistic Submarine Paradox.
A quick synopsis of the submarine paradox:
Consider a submarine that is neutrally buoyant when stationary relative to the water.
Frame 1)  The observer is at rest with the water and the Earth. The sub is moving horizontally relative to the observer. It is denser and displaces less water than when it at rest, so it should sink, according to this observer.
Frame 2) The observer is comoving horizontally with the submarine. They see no length contraction of the submarine, so the displaced volume of water is not reduced in this case. Worse still, they also see the density of the water has increased due to its relative motion, so overall the submarine should float upwards in this reference frame, but this is a contradiction to what is seen in Frame 1.
=============================================================
Supplee came up with his own solution, that was along the lines of the sea bed curving upwards from the point of view of someone on the moving submarine. Not even Supplee was very convinced by his own explanation as he readily conceded the explanation given by George Matsas in 2018 using general relativity was better. However, to his credit Supplee came up with the same equations obtained by Matsas. Later still, Vieira published his solution that involves the concept of curved time and the gravitomagnetic effect. He also came up with the same equations of relativistic buoyancy.
All these worthy papers involve concepts and a level of knowledge beyond what a student new to relativity would be expected to have.
We can reason that in a weak gravitational field, such as that of the Earth, the gravitational effects on time dilation etc. would be negligible compared to dynamic effects of highly relativistic horizontal velocities, such as 0.99c, so it should be possible to find a solution using mostly the equations of Special Relativity alone.
So, is there an simple derivation of the solution to the Submarine Paradox in terms of Special Relativity?

The solution to this paradox is highly informative as it gives a feel to tangible measurable effects of length contraction, time dilation, density increase and relativistic mass and how they are all inter related.
I will introduce the subject with 3 short thought experiments that will tell us how gravitational acceleration transforms with relative motion.
Thought Experiment 1) Consider a projectile that is fired horizontally from height h. Let's say the the object would normally take time (t) to fall to the ground from height (h), according to an observer standing on the surface the Earth. The equivalence principle tells us the horizontal velocity does not affect the rate it falls at.
We can conclude that the acceleration of gravity on an object with non zero velocity relative to the observer and the Earth is:
$$g_{EO} = g \tag{Eq1}$$
Thought Experiment 2) Now consider the same situation but the observer is comoving horizontally with the object. In this situation, the object only has motion relative to the Earth, so there is no gamma factor due to motion relative to the observer. Due to time dilation this observer will measure the time to fall as shorter than that measured by the ground observer by a factor of gamma and the acceleration to be greater by a factor of gamma$^2$.
$$g_{E} = g \ \gamma_E^2 = \frac{g}{(1-v_E^2/c^2)} \tag{Eq2}$$
Since there is no motion relative to the observer in this case, we have to conclude that the transformation of the acceleration is entirely due to the motion of the object relative to the gravitational body $(v_E)$.
Thought Experiment 3) Now consider the situation where the object has no horizontal motion relative to the Earth surface so it is falling straight down, but in this case, the Earth and the object are moving together relative to an observer in space. Now the object has motion relative to the observer but not to the Earth. This observer measures the time to fall as longer by a gamma factor proportional to the velocity of the object relative to himself and therefore sees the gravitational acceleration as slowed down by a factor of gamma$^2$:
$$g_{O} = g \ \gamma_O^{2} = g \ (1-v_O^2/c^2) \tag{Eq3}$$
When $|V_E| = |V_O| \ne 0$, as in the first scenario, multiplying the gamma factors in (2) and (3) gives us:
$$\gamma_E \gamma_O  = \frac{\sqrt{1-v_O^2/c^2}}{\sqrt{1-v_E^2/c^2}} = 1 , $$
which is in complete agreement with conclusion (Eq1).
The above equations tell us that the gravitational acceleration experienced by an object moving horizontally in a weak gravitational field, is not only affected by the velocity relative to the observer, but also by the velocity relative to the gravitational body. When the object has motion relative to a gravitational body the acceleration it is subjected to, increases by a factor of gamma squared using the velocity relative to the gravitational body. See (Eq2) below. It is important to note that the gamma factors $\gamma_O$ and $\gamma_E$ derived below only apply to vertical acceleration and use the velocity of the object relative the observer ($v_O$) and relative to the Earth ($v_E$) respectively. The object can be any object with mass, e.g. a submarine or a block of water.
=====================================================================
Now we have a good idea how vertical acceleration due to gravity transforms when there is horizontal motion relative to a gravitational body, we are ready to tackle the submarine paradox itself.
Solution to the paradox:
By Archimedes' principle, the upward buoyant force on an object is equal to the weight of water that is displaced. We can write this as
$$F_{up} = m_{water}\  g$$
$$ \implies \rho_{water} \ V_{sub} \ g_{water},$$
where $(\rho_{water} )$ is the density of displaced water and $V_{sub}$ is the volume of the submarine (and therefore also the volume of the displace water). Density transforms as $(\rho')= \rho \gamma^2$ when the object is moving relative to the observer, due to relativistic mass increase and length contraction combined.
In the following equations ($\gamma$) without a subscript, is just the normal gamma factor of special relativity that is a function of the velocity of the object relative to the observer.
Initial Reference parameters:  The submarine is neutrally buoyant when fully submerged and at rest with the water and the Earth, such that the downward force $F_{down} $ and the upward buoyancy force $F_{up}$ are equal in magnitude and both equal to the weight of the submarine so that $F_{down} = F_{up} = mg$, where m is the mass of the submarine and g is the regular acceleration of gravity.
Frame 1) When the sub is moving horizontally relative to a observer that is at rest with the Earth and the water, the upward buoyant force is:
$$F_{up1} = (\rho_{water} ) (V_{sub} \ \gamma^{-1}) \ g_{water} $$
$$\implies F_{up1} = \gamma^{-1} (\rho_{water}  \  V_{sub} \ g_{water}) = \gamma^{-1} (m g) \tag{Eq4} $$
Note that in this frame the water is not moving relative to the observer so there is no change in the water density.
The downward force on the submarine in this scenario is:
$$F_{down1} = (m_{sub} \gamma)(g_{sub} \gamma_E^2 \gamma_O^2) = (m_{sub} \gamma)g_{sub}$$
$$\implies F_{down1} = \gamma (mg) \tag{Eq5}$$
The net force on the sub in this reference frame is:
$$F_1 = F_{up1} - F_{down1} = mg(\gamma^{-1} - \gamma) \tag{Eq6},$$
which is negative, so the sub sinks in this reference frame.
======================================================================
Frame 2) When the observer is comoving horizontally with the sub, the sub has motion relative to the water and the Earth but not to the observer and the water has motion only relative to the observer, the upward force is:
$$F_{up2} = (\rho_{water} \gamma^2 ) (V_{sub})  (g_{water} \gamma_O^{2} ) = (\rho_{water} \gamma^2 ) (V_{sub})  (g_{water} \gamma^{-2} )$$
$$\implies F_{up2} = (\rho_{water}  \  V_{sub} \ g_{water}) \tag{Eq7}$$
The downward force on the submarine according to the observer comoving horizontally with the sub in this scenario is:
$$F_{down2} = m_{sub} (g_{sub} \gamma_E^2) = m_{sub}  (g_{sub}\gamma^2) $$
$$\implies F_{down2}= \gamma^2 (mg) \tag{Eq8}$$
The net force (Eq7) - (Eq8) in this reference frame is:
$$F_2 = F_{up2} - F_{down2} = mg(1 - \gamma^2) \tag{Eq9},$$
which is negative, so the sub also sinks in this reference frame and the paradox is resolved.
======================================================================
Note that the ratio between the net force in scenario (S1) where the sub is moving relative to the observer  and the net force in scenario (S2) where the sub is at rest with respect to the observer is:
$$\frac{(Eq6)}{(Eq9)} = \frac{F(\gamma^{-1} - \gamma)}{F(1 - \gamma^2)} = \frac{1}{\gamma},$$
which is in complete agreement with the Lorentz transformation of transverse force with relative motion.
Equations (6) and (9) are also in agreement with the equations derived by Supplee, Matsas and Vieira, but here we only used the equations of special relativity (and the equivalence principle) and arrived at the same result.
In conclusion, changes in density do have the effects assumed in the naïve interpretation of the submarine paradox, but the paradox is resolved by observing that the acceleration of gravity on an object is affected by the horizontal motion of the object relative to the gravitational body.

Something about thought experiment 1 doesn't add up for me. Perhaps you mean the projectile is shot vertically at first?

No, I meant horizontal. Even a photon projected horizontally will hit the floor at the same time a heavy object dropped vertically. See this video https://youtu.be/_t8TpMJm-RU?t=95 and tell me which bit you disagree with or where my description disagrees with the equivalence principle, please.

Got it, I thought that you're taking two distinct cases, one where it's fired horizontally from an unspecified height (I thought actually you meant, fired from the surface level of earth which I guess is silly). All is clear now

@KDP In $\text{(Eq3)}$ you are multiplying by $\gamma_O^2$ , but that would lead to a factor of $\dfrac{1}{1-v_O^2/c^2}$, the reciprocal of what you wrote. Did you mean to divide by it? Then, how does that affect the expression you give for $\gamma_E\gamma_O$? Again, the square root can't be in the numerator in such an expression. Did you also mean that these gammas are to be divided? As an aside, you're missing a square on $v_E$ in $\text{(Eq2)}$

Hi @Amit   In (Eq3) I intended to define $\gamma_O$ as $\sqrt{(1-v_O^2/c^2)}$ as per the text immediately preceding the equation: ("therefore sees the gravitational acceleration as slowed down by a factor of gamma$^2$"). You are right that I am missing a square on $v_E$
in (Eq2). . I will fix that typo.
:

I deleted my last comment, it had a mistake in it. Anyway yes I need to read the answer again, now that I get the general intent. Thanks

@Amit  Thankyou for proof reading my answer. Much appreciated :-)

a question if you don't mind me bugging you again: would it be equivalent to define the three frames of the thought experiment as: 1. Stationary observer on earth's frame (relative velocity has both vertical and horizontal components.) 2. The falling object frame (comoving with object, only the earth has vertical velocity) 3. Horizontally comoving surface frame (the object has vertical velocity, earth is stationary).
The reason why I find it simpler is just the way the velocity notation suggests itself: $v_{EO}$ - earth-object $v_E$ earth's velocity, $v_O$ - object's velocity.

@Amit You are no bother at all. I was thing of calling the 3 thought experiments as simply 3 different reference frames or points of view, but that would not be entirely accurate as they are 3 different scenarios and not simply the same scenario from 3 different points of view.  I have intentionally avoided the vertical aspect of the motion as far as time dilation goes, as the change in velocity when vertically falling a couple of metres is negligible compared to the horizontal velocity and the difference in gravitational time dilation due to the difference in height is also negligible.

With regard to the 3 frames you defined. Frame : Yes, but to be clear, the relative velocity is that of the sub relative to the Earth. Frame 2: Yes, only the Earth has vertical velocity but don't forget the Earth also has horizontal velocity in this scenario. Frame 3: You describe the Earth as stationary. This is only true horizontally relative to the falling sub, but it is not true relative to the observer. I agree it is difficult to keep track of everything, as there are a lot of things going on simultaneously. I might try and make a table to clarify the relative velocities.
